# Did Law & Order ever feature a US Supreme Court trial?

Tags: law-and-order

Has any episode of the original Law & Order (1990-2010) featured an appearance before the US Supreme Court?

There are numerous episodes where McCoy appears before the NY Supreme Court, but has there been any higher court presented? If not the Supreme Court, were there any US District Court appearances?

There are many episodes with an outro describing what happened in higher-level courts. I'm specifically asking about portrayals of the proceedings.

Comment: In New York State, unusually,  the Supreme Court is the trial court for civil and criminal cases in each of the 62 counties.  The highest court in NY state is called the Court of Appeals and not the NY State Supreme Court, unlike most states.  So Law & Order's Supreme Court is just an ordinary court and not the supreme court of the state of New York, which instead uses the title of Court of Appeals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Supreme_Court

Comment: Thanks! That explains why so many episodes feature a Supreme Court appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one! S10 E24, *Vaya con Dios*. McCoy successfully prosecutes a Chilean national, who receives an expedited hearing before the US Supreme Court. McCoy appears before the court.